# Is there a way to make a big loop work in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a 10x10 grid with a for loop in React. But React doesn't let me perform this function because it says that it exceed the maximum of actions performed. Is there a way to generate this 10x10 grid without the use of the loop?

Any help I would really appreciate it. I'm building the battleship project.

```
import React, {useEffect  ,useState} from 'react'
import Ship from '../components/ShipGenerate.js'
import '../style/style.css'



function Grid(props) {

    const [grid, setGrid] = useState([])

console.log(grid)
  useEffect(() => {

    // Here we push the result boxes to random generated arrays in different positions. We put it inside a useEffect so it only changes the array once

    for (i = 0; i < props.data[0].size; i++) {

      let result = randomNumberArray.map(function(val){return ++val;})
      let finalResult = randomNumberArray.push(result[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[1].size; i++) {

    let result2 = randomNumberArray2.map(function(val) {return ++val})
    let secondResult = randomNumberArray2.push(result2[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[2].size; i++) {

    let result = randomNumberArray3.map(function(val){return ++val;})
    let finalResult = randomNumberArray3.push(result[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[3].size; i++) {

  let result2 = randomNumberArray4.map(function(val) {return ++val})
  let secondResult = randomNumberArray4.push(result2[i])
  }

  for (i = 0; i < props.data[4].size; i++) {

  let result2 = randomNumberArray5.map(function(val) {return ++val})
  let secondResult = randomNumberArray5.push(result2[i])
  }

}, [])


    let randomNumberArray = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray2 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray3 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray4 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))
    let randomNumberArray5 = [...Array(1)].map(()=>(Math.random() * 7 | 0) + 11 * (Math.random() * 10 | 0))

    // We generate the 10x10 grid
    
for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
   if (randomNumberArray.includes(i)) {    // ---> checking with this condition if the index in the random array to give it a different className
      setGrid([...grid,<button className="hello"></button>])
    }
      else if (randomNumberArray2.includes(i)) {
        setGrid([...grid,<button className="hello"></button>])
      }
      else if (randomNumberArray3.includes(i)) {
        setGrid([...grid,<button className="hello"></button>])
      }
      else if (randomNumberArray4.includes(i)) {
      setGrid([...grid,<button className="hello"></button>])
      }
      else if (randomNumberArray5.includes(i)) {
        setGrid([...grid,<button className="hello"></button>])
      }
       else {
      setGrid([...grid,<button className="boxGrid"></button>])
   }
}

const onClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.textContent = "x"
  props.setTurn(false)
}



    return (
        <div>
  <div onClick={onClick} className="box">
    {grid}
  </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Grid
```

Comment: Not sure I totally understand; why not generate the data for the grid and just generate it all at once instead of piling on `setGrid` calls?

Comment: Not sure were to start, unfortunately the code you posted is doesn't really make much sense.  Your `e.target.textContent` is certainly not the React way.  Are you just after a 10x10 grid, and when you click a cell an X appears..?  As it might make more sense for someone to knock up a simple snippet doing this.#

Comment: Because the data should be different boxes with different sizes... @DaveNewton

Comment: setState callbacks cause a react update, so your app is recursively rebuilding itself. It's not the loop's fault. Also, you are generating the ship placement every time the board re-renders. Which means that the ships are going to move around unpredictably.

Comment: @CharlesBamford should we put the for loop inside the useEffect then?

Comment: `useEffect`, unless you are getting some data async or using DOM ref's, isn't really needed.

Comment: No. You should be figuring out where your ships belong, setting those into state with useState(), then never changing it. It's not the loop's fault.

Comment: I don't get why you're `map`ping over a single element when declaring the `randomArray`* arrays. Also, you could just create an array of arrays and save yourself five `else if` branches, and the five separate loops in the `useEffect`.

Comment: Are we making the game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)

Comment: @keith yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to figure out how your trying to create the game, and correct it.

I thought it might be easier to create a simple example that you could use as a starting point.

Below is a 10x10 grid, I've randomly created ships, I'll leave it to you to update to create proper ships etc, and handle players & game logic.

```js
const {useState} = React;

let board;

function createBoard() {
  //create battlefield board
  board = new Array(10);
  for (let i=0; i<board.length; i+=1) 
    board[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);
  const rnd = r => Math.trunc(Math.random() * r);
  //board values
  //0 = empty
  //1  = ship
  //2 = empty missed shot
  //3 = ship hit

  //fill some random ship
  for (let l=0; l<40;l +=1) {
    board[rnd(10)][rnd(10)] = 1;
  }
}

createBoard();

function Piece(p) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(board[p.y][p.x]);
  const cls = ['piece'];
  let txt = '.';
  if (value === 2) cls.push('empty-shot');
  if (value === 3) { cls.push('boom'); txt = '*' }
  return <div 
    onClick={() => {
      let c = board[p.y][p.x];
      if (c > 1) return;
      if (c === 0) c = 2;
      else if (c === 1) c = 3;
      board[p.y][p.x] = c;
      setValue(c);
    }}
    className={cls.join(' ')}>
    {txt}
  </div>
}

function Board() {
  return <div className="board">{
    board.map((b,iy) =>
      <div key={iy}>
        {b.map((a,ix) => <Piece key={ix} x={ix} y={iy}/>)}
      </div>
  )}</div>
}

function Game() {
  const [gameCount, setGameCount] = useState(1);
  return <div>
     <div style={{marginBottom: "1rem"}}><button onClick={() => {
       createBoard();
       setGameCount(c => c + 1);
     }}>Clear</button></div>
     <Board key={gameCount}/>
  </div>
}


ReactDOM.render(<Game/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```css
.board {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0.3em solid black;
}

.piece {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: cyan;
  border: 0.2em solid black;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.piece.empty-shot {
  color: white;
  background-color: navy;
}

.piece.boom {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="mount"></div>
```